# SpringBoot microservice @StreamListener retry unlimited time when it throw RunTimeException

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a @StreamListener method where it will perform REST call. When REST call return exception, @StreamListener method will throw RunTimeException and perform retry. @StreamListener method will retry unlimited times when it throw RuntimeException

Spring Cloud Stream Retry configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.enableDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.maxAttempts=3
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.concurrency=3
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.backOffInitialInterval=300000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.backOffMaxInterval=600000
```

SpringBoot microservice dependencies version:

```
Spring Boot 2.0.3
Spring Cloud Stream Elmhurst.RELEASE
Kafka broker 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using RetryTemplate or increasing maxAttempts property has the restriction that retries should be completed within `max.poll.interval.ms`, otherwise Kafka broker will think that consumer is down and reassigns the partition to another consumer(if available).

Other option is to make the listener re-read the same message from Kafka using `consumer.seek` method.

```
@StreamListener("events")
public void handleEvent(@Payload String eventString, @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                             @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partitionId,
                             @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                             @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) {
   try {
       //do the logic (example: REST call)
   } catch (Exception e) { // Catch only specific exceptions that can be retried
        consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, Integer.parseInt(partitionId)), Long.parseLong(offset));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly increase the number of attempts (`maxAttempts` property) to something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or you can provide an instance of your own `RetryTemplate` bean which could be configured as you wish.
Here is where you can get more info https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_template

Answer (score 0):

after a few trial and error, we found out that kafka configuration: **max.poll.interval.ms** is defaulted to 5 minutes. Due to our consumer retry mechanism, our whole retry process will take 15 minutes for the worst case scenario.

So after 5 minutes of the first message being consumed, kafka partition decides that consumer did not provide any response, do a auto-balancing and assign the same message to another partition.